# After fitting a GuassianProcessRegressor with a composite kernel, can we make predictions using only parts of the kernel?

Tags: scikit-learn, gaussian

The contrived example below shows a Gaussian process regression with a composite kernal can be used to fit trends at different length scales. In the example below the maximum-likelihood kernel is `0.492**2 * RBF(length_scale=9.97e+04) + 2.14**2 * RBF(length_scale=1e-05)` - showing we have detected two length scales. Is it possible to make a prediction on each length scale (or otherwise de-compose the final prediction) to see the effects of each part of the kernal?

A better example is considering the Mauna Loa CO2 data in the documentation at https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/gaussian_process.html. This replicates the results in the paper referenced in the documentation. The paper however shows plots of the slow/fast/seasonal contributions of the kernal components. Can we replicate this kind of analysis using `scikit-learn`'s `GaussianProcessRegressor`?

```py
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import RBF, WhiteKernel, ConstantKernel

kernel = ConstantKernel() * RBF() + ConstantKernel() * RBF( )
gp = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel, n_restarts_optimizer=10)

import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = 3*np.sin(x) + np.sin(x*5)

gp.fit(x.reshape(-1, 1), y)
print(gp.kernel_)

# We can make predictions using both components of the kernel:
#  is it possible to make predictions on each component 
#  individually?
y_hat = gp.predict(x.reshape(-1, 1))
```